# get neighbors of specific node in python using iGraph

Tags: python, igraph

I am trying to get the neighbors of a specific node in my graph. Graph looks like this

```
print g

IGRAPH UN-- 6 3 --
+ attr: name (v), position (v)
+ edges (vertex names):
40--115, 116--98, 44--98

g.vs['name]
[116, 40, 44, 115, 98, 116]
```

I have tried to use the following to get the neighbors of `40`

```
g.neighbors(g.vs['name'][1])
```

but I get the following error:

```
InternalError: Error at type_indexededgelist.c:750: cannot get neighbors, Invalid vertex id
```

I have also tried this, but get a different error

```
g.neighbors('40')

ValueError: no such vertex: '40'
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the function *neighbors* a string, but it expects an integer or Vertex object. try:

```
g.neighbors(g.vs[1])
```

or

```
g.neighbors(1)
```